# Forcing BlackBerry to do a hard restart after app installation

Tags: blackberry, connection, restart

I've been experiencing unexplained connection issues with my BB app. This only happens on a Curve 8520, and only on some of them. There is no noticeable pattern so i cant determine what causes it. The app prompts me to check my internet connection even though all other apps / browsers are working fine.

The only solution is to do a manual hard restart after installation. This solved the problem and the app runs seamlessly 100% of the time.

Is there a way to prompt the user to restart the phone after initial installation has been completed? Ex. Like some RIM products, after you've installed it prompts you to restart now or later, if you select yes it does a complete / hard restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK when a BlackBerry application is set "Run on startup" it runs automatically as it is installed.

And you may use [requestPowerOff](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Device.html#requestPowerOff%28boolean%29) method of Device class to turn the device off and automatically turn it on (this is controlled by the method parameter).